# Postgresql UPSERT with multiple unique constraints

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have one table created as location (cities in the world).

```
CREATE TABLE location (
    location_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    location_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state_id INT,
    country_id INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (location_name, state_id, country_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES state (state_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country (country_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX loc_1_uni_idx ON location (location_name, country_id)
    WHERE state_id IS NULL;
```

This table has two uniqueness check: location_name + country_id if state_id is null, and location_name + state_id + country_id if state_id has value.

Currently I would like to perform upsert into this table. I could perform on conflict for either cases mentioned above:

```
INSERT INTO location(location_name, state_id, country_id) VALUES %s 
ON CONFLICT (location_name, state_id, country_id) 
DO UPDATE 
   SET country_id = EXCLUDED.country_id 
RETURNING location_id;

INSERT INTO location(location_name, state_id, country_id) VALUES %s 
ON CONFLICT (location_name, country_id) 
   WHERE state_id IS NULL 
DO UPDATE SET country_id = EXCLUDED.country_id 
RETURNING location_id;
```

However, as state_id may or may not present, how could I perform one upsert to fulfill both situations? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the rationale behind the second unique constraint.  It seems to be redundant.  What is the logic here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do you mean the unique index? If I do not set this, as state_id can be null, and null value is not unique, I would end up with multiple duplicates for (location_name, state_id, country_id) like (Singapore, NULL, Singapore_id).